# PicklingError when starting working with Celery in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, celery

I hope to use Celery / RabbitMQ to run regualr interval tasks in a Flask app on Windows 7 and Python 3.3. Pip installs:

```
billiard==3.3.0.10
celery==3.1.6
```

The code:

```py
### celeryapp.py ###
from celery import Celery
from twend import config, app

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

celery_pipe = make_celery(app)
celery_pipe.config_from_object(config)

### tasks.py ###
from celery import task
from twend.celeryapp import celery_pipe as celery

@celery.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b

### config.py ###
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
```

When I try to start the worker I get:

```py
ERROR/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: PicklingError(
"Can't pickle <class 'module'>: attribute lookup builtins.module failed",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python33\twend\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\__init__.py", line 212
, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "c:\Python33\twend\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 123, in s
tart
    step.start(parent)
  File "c:\Python33\twend\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 373, in s
tart
    return self.obj.start()
  File "c:\Python33\twend\lib\site-packages\celery\concurrency\base.py", line 12
7, in start
    self.on_start()
  File "c:\Python33\twend\lib\site-packages\celery\concurrency\prefork.py", line
 112, in on_start
    **self.options)
  File "c:\Python33\twend\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 966, in __in
it__
    self._create_worker_process(i)
  File "c:\Python33\twend\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 1059, in _cr
eate_worker_process
    w.start()
  File "c:\Python33\twend\lib\site-packages\billiard\process.py", line 139, in s
tart
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "c:\Python33\twend\lib\site-packages\billiard\forking.py", line 263, in _
_init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "c:\Python33\twend\lib\site-packages\billiard\_reduction3.py", line 60, i
n dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'module'>: attribute lookup builtins.
module failed

(twend) c:\Python33\twend>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python33\twend\lib\site-packages\billiard\forking.py", line 457, in m
ain
    self = load(from_parent)
EOFError
```

This https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/228 seems like a similar problem but was fixed in the version of Celery I am using.

I've also read that Windows has restrictions regarding pickling but I am not sure what is actually being pickled.

Answer (score -1):

Celery uses pickling for serializing tasks and results.  I see that you already are setting your config to only accept json serialization, so maybe you can fix your problem by adding a couple more config lines:

```
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

This way, pickle won't be used at all, and all of Celery's serialization will be done using json.  This can theoretically cause a performance hit, but I solved a similar problem in my Flask app this way and didn't notice any performance issues.  YMMV